# Apache beam Python SDK

Tags: apache-beam

So I have a python file which has code related to rest api to extract from a url and load it in a sql database. The code contains python packages such as graphql to extract the data and sqlalchemy to inject the data into the database. I’m trying integrate this code into beam api, but I have no clue how to do so. Do I have to generate the data first and then use the csv output for my pipeline or can I just insert all of this into a beam pipeline and extract the csv by executing the apache beam code? Any help is extremely appreciated thank you for reading.

I am not going to share any code, im just here to understand how to tackle this problem so that I can look for solutions myself!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why you are looking into integrating Beam? To solve what problem/downside of the current code? What database you are using? In general, it seems that you could extract the data from a URL from within a Beam DoFn, and output it to a PCollection, and then using one of the [Beam's Built-in I/O Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/) to save them into a database. But I would need more details to be able to help you more. Please also look at the [Apache Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi bruno thank you for your reply, So I have a .py file which retrieves a csv file using rest api, my goal is to use beam and its methods to call this python api and convert output to csv using pardo or map methods. So im failing to understand if i should be translating all this code in the .py file to the beam programming syntax or can i just simply reference this py file in beam to get the output and simply process it to GCP big query.

Comment: You can reuse your existing functions with Beam. Did you take a look at the [WordCount example](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/)? It will give you some pointers on how to start (it extracts the frequency from specific files, so the model can be translated to your needs.